# Convert classified point matrix to shapefile

Tags: shapefile, r

I've use R to generate a matrix of points tagged to separate categories. Each point has a lat, long. and category. When I plot them in QGIS (using colored points of the appropriate size) it looks like a territory map - which is the application. The points cluster together in discernible market areas.

[image]

I would like to use R to generate shapefiles which follow the color boundaries and which contain the appropriate classification label. I would use those market boundary shapefiles in a variety of other applications.

The size of the matrix is 10000 x 10000.

Comment: you need to convert this grid of points (its a regularly spaced grid in some coordinate system, yes?) and then use a raster-to-vector process, eg `raster::rasterToPolygons` - might struggle on a 10k x 10k pixel raster unless you have lots of RAM though. Try it.

Comment: Please decide which particular GIS software you wish to ask about in this particular question. Since @Spacedman has already suggested R may be fruitful I suggest you [edit] your question to focus on that. You can always ask about QGIS and Python in separate questions.

Comment: Edited to focus on R.

Comment: Further clarification: the density of the matrix is 100 x 100. All of the "rasterize" commands I've reviewed have required numeric feature data (e.g. grayscale or elevations). This application is entirely categorical.

Comment: If you just need to convert to polygons, I think you can assign numerical codes to each category (e.g. yellow=1, blue=2, etc.), convert to polygons and then label those polygons with the appropriate categories. This answer deals with a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606557/r-convert-raster-to-individual-polygons . Also, `spex::polygonize` is reasonably fast.